# Pagination is not working with Page List

Tags: sxa

I am working on Sitecore.NET 9.1.1 (rev. 002459). Yes I have added unique List Signature fields value in both PageList and Pagination components.
I have created a Page Design which has column splitter component. In column 1-1 I added page List and populated the data from an Item Query using the Component Editor Field **Source Type**. I didn't set any value to the Field **Page Size**.
Below that I tried to put a Pagination Component in the experience editor but it asks to add the associated content but there is no component to add there. Below is the screen shot.
[image]
So I added it from Content Editor in **Presentation -> Details** and added Field **Collapse Pagination Threshold** to 6 (I have more than 6 elements in my Page List).

Then I mapped both these components using unique **List Signature** field value.

But it is showing all the Page List elements and No Pagination on the Web page.

Comment: Could you please add some details on how you have configured both components and also on what sitecore version? I assume that you have a unique signature defined in your list signature fields?

Comment: @CristiVulturar I have edited my Question.

Comment: Have you tried to click the Create button to create a Page Selector datasource for the pagination? If it doesn't have a datasource the button First/Previous/Next/Last will be empty.

Comment: @CristiVulturar: I had tried that, and it gave me 2 options i.e. Page Selector Configuration and Pagination Folder. I chose the first one but it says "Pagination is Empty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue in Page Size Field. I tried increasing the number of items and giving Page Size less than the item number and it worked.